# Update counter with AJAX call to database wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm counting votes on my website and when user submit the form, I want an ajax call that updates the total number of votes that is shown on the bottom of the page. I do this by counting number of rows in the table, like this:

```
$rowcount = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _db7_forms");
```

This code works, now I wanna call it again when user submitted the form.

Hard to explain so I Show the code instead:

Where I show the number of votes:

```
 <h1 class="intro"><?php echo $rowcount; ?>00000</h1>
```

The ajax call (I'm calling the function in another functions and I've tested it so it works):

```
function updateVotes(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                type: 'post',
                data: ({
                    action: "callDB"
                }),
                success: function (response){
                    console.log(response);
                    jQuery(".intro").html(response);
                }
            });
        }
```

The query that check numbers of votes:

```
function callDB() {
    $rowcount = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _db7_forms");
}
```

This is what I got and I haven't really worked with AJAX before so i dont relly understand what I've written. The error I get now is **myurl.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)**
The url is correct though and that file exists.

Just to make clear: The error given isn't my only problem, I'm positive that it won't give me the result I want. I need help with the next steps too.

Comment: Do you call exactly the same Ajax function in another function successfully, or did you change it at all for this usage (changing the `url` value, perhaps)?

Comment: Do you know for certain if `updateVotes()` or `callDB` is throwing the error?

Comment: @223seneca I'm only calling this function when the form is successully submitted

Comment: How do I test that?

Comment: Did you actually add `add_action( 'wp_ajax_callDB', 'callDB' );` (for logged-in users) and/or `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_callDB', 'callDB' );` (for logged-out users) somewhere before or after the `callDB` function? And in `callDB()`, you did have something like `echo $rowcount; exit;`, right?

Comment: @Sally no I didn't... but now I have it and it removes the error but dont update the `<h1>` tag

Comment: @teninchhero, change this line `jQuery(".intro").text(response);`

Comment: @teninchhero, try *vel*'s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try like this?

```
function callDB() {
    global $wpdb;
    $rowcount = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts");
    echo $rowcount;
    exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_callDB', 'callDB' ); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_callDB', 'callDB' );


    function updateVotes(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: ({
                action: "callDB"
            }),
            success: function (response){
                console.log(response);
                jQuery(".intro").text(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Okay so now it makes the ajax call but doesnt send back the right thing to the `<h1>`, which makes sense because I just echo it? How do I send a value with `response`?

Comment: OKay it worked!! I saw now that you used another db table! Thanks!!